# Load auth component. CakePHP 1.3.

Tags: cakephp, authentication, components, cakephp-1.3

I'm using custom AuthComponent (AppAuthComponent) and I don't want to load it in one controller, because this controller is using his own auth methods.

Now in beforeFilter I check if I need to load Auth

```
if(isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
      $this->_initAuth();
}
```

And I've created method for loading component

```
public function _loadComponent($componentName) {
    $componentCn = $componentName . 'Component';
    if(App::import('Component', $componentName)) {
        $this->{$componentName} = new $componentCn();
        $this->{$componentName}->enabled = true;
        $this->Component->_loadComponents($this->{$componentName});
        $this->{$componentName}->initialize($this);
        $this->{$componentName}->startup($this);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But Acl is not working...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you have any error messages/exceptions or does it not behave as you exspected?

Comment: Because Acl maybe is not working, maybe this code is not initializing Acl.